# Entwicklung gegen Entwickelt

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich möchte nur wissen, welche Grammatikregel in den folgenden Sätzen verwendet wird.

```
Entwicklung einer Application für ein Wohnheim der Universität.
```

Wenn ich das geschrieben hätte, würde ich das so machen:

```
Entwickelt eine Application für ein Wohnheim der Universität.
```

Entwicklung gegen Entwickelt hier. 
Ich bin mir sicher, dass es etwas mit Genitiv zu tun hat, aber ich kann es trotzdem nicht verstehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Entwicklung*** ist ein Substantiv.

***Entwickelt*** kann sein

a) ein Partizip Perfekt des Verbs *entwickeln* (*to develop --> developed*), oder

b) die dritte Person Einzahl dieses Verbs (*he develops*).

*Entwickelt* ist nie ein Substantiv.

Dein Satz *Entwickelt eine Application für ein Wohnheim der Universität* ist einfach falsch. Es sei denn, man unterstellte, er sei Teil einer Aufzählung wie etwa

> Paul macht sehr viel für unser Unternehmen. Er
>
> - entwickelt eine Application für ein Wohnheim der Universität
> - berät Bestandskunden
> - sorgt dafür, dass immer Kaffee da ist

Aber das ist ein sehr spezieller Fall, und so etwas hast du wohl nicht im Sinn gehabt.

***Entwickeln*** (das Verb) kann auch als Substantiv auftreten:

> Das Entwickeln von Software-Anwendungen macht mir großen Spaß.

Man kann den bestimmten Artkel auch weglassen. Dann sieht der Satz so aus:

> Entwickeln von Software-Anwendungen macht mir großen Spaß.

Vielleicht wolltest du auf so etwas hinaus und hast *entwickeln* und *entwickelt* verwechselt?

Man kann das *Entwickeln* auch im Genitiv verwenden:

> Die schönste Seite des **Entwickelns** von Software ist, dass man dabei still am Schreibtisch sitzen kann und doch etwas Schöpferisches macht.

Comment: Eine weitere Möglichkeit wäre eine Aufforderung/ein Befehl an eine Gruppe von Personen (zum Beispiel Studenten): "Entwickelt eine Applikation!". Der Text klingt für mich nach Aufgabenstellung.